# How to pass a querystring and override a different querystring to AWS Lambda from Amazon API Gateway ? What will be the Mapping template

Tags: aws-lambda, lambda, aws-api-gateway

How to pass a querystring and override a different querystring  to AWS Lambda from Amazon API Gateway ? What will be the Mapping template .

I want to modify in this template .

```
#set($newProductKey = "4567")
##normal body mapping. In this case, just pass the body mapping through **
$input.json("$")
## Override query string parameters **
#set($context.requestOverride.querystring.productId = $newProductKey)
{
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  },
  "pathParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }  
}
```